# AS3 creating Walls using CDK for collisions

Tags: actionscript-3, collision

Hi in my project there is a sprite moving and i need to define collisions against walls. These walls are not regular shapes, so I'm using CDK for a better collision detection. How can I forbid my character to step on walls objects?

Comment: It's hard to help without any code you have tried. Atleast, show the part of code where you are having issues.

Comment: I still don't know where to start from, i've no idea about any developing strategy I should adopt, anyways I was thinking about placing 4 hitArea objects in the player symbol to detect where the wall is (left,right,up,down) and forbid to move in that direction... what you think